# Android - TextView in a Custom ListView loses its content while scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview

I have came across these type of questions a lot, But none of the answers solved my problem.

I am developing a mobile shopping application model. I have a custom `ListView` with an `ImageView`, and `EditText`(quantity), 2 `Buttons` for increasing and decreasing the quantity, 3 `TextView`s one for item Name and other two for prices and I am dynamically loading a number of Buttons for NetWeights based on the requirement through Java code and I am implementing it using CustomAdapter(Class) extending `BaseAdapter` and getView().

**Problem 1:**

When I use the condition `if(convertView==null), setTag(holder)` and `getTag()`, the dynamically loaded Buttons are getting duplicated and gets doubled in number.

**Problem 2:**

While scrolling the custom `ListView` I am loosing my data on 2 of the `TextView`s while the other `TextView`(name) is fine because in that `TextView` I don't Change data on runtime. On the other two `TextView`s(prices) I change the data on runtime using ButtonClicks(increase and decrease) where at that time when I scroll the two `TextView`s, it looses its content. Actually I had this same problem with the EditText(displaying quantity), I solved it using the `TextWatcher` by getting the value and passing it in an array and again setting it. I used the same technique (i.e) the `TextWatcher` for the `TextView`s But that did'nt Help. I also tried removing the TextWatcher and setting the text with the array and adding `TextWatcher`. Still I am loosing my content in those `TextView`s

Any Suggestions??????

Comment: try to use recyclerview instead of listview

Comment: post your adapter class

Comment: @shayanpourvatan, actually my code is too long, stackoverflow is not allowing me to post such a long code :(

Comment: ok @SathishKumarJ, I ll try it and update the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:**
While using ViewHolder (setTag(), getTag()) we will be reusing the views.
For example: Let's say we have 10 listview items and the screen can display 3 items at a time. Lets say we add 2 buttons to list item 1. First time when we load the listview we will see two buttons. Lets say now we scroll down and come back to the list item 1 again, as we are reusing the views, we already have 2 buttons and if we have the code to add buttons using getTag() then 2 more buttons will be added. I think this may be causing the issue of button duplication. To add little more information, list item 1, list item 4, list item 7 and list item 10 will all use same view, as our screen in this example can display just 3 items.

**Problem 2:**
One idea is to store all these text values in the arrayList. 
For example, lets assume we have one textView inside each list item that can be incremented/ decremented. Set textWatcher on this textView and whenever text changes add it to the arrrayList using 'position' as the index. Inside getView method when you do getTag() try to set the textView using previously stored text (that was stored inside the arrayList)if exists.

Comment: For Problem 2, I have already tired your suggestion. It worked for EditText but did'nt work for TextView :(. And my another doubt is when your suggestion works for EditText, why is it not working for TextView?

Comment: For Problem 1, I think what you are telling is right. That must be the problem. So, how would you suggest me to solve it.

Comment: I solved the duplication problem (i.e) Problem 1. Thanks  :)

Comment: But still the Problem 2 is standing :(

Comment: Yay, Problem 2 got solved while solving Problem 1 :D. But new problem occured :(

Comment: Problem 2 occurred again :(